# How to add borough's and do the selection

Tags: postgresql

Which neighborhood has the most people under 21 years old in each borough?

This is the coding that I've already done in pgadmin:

```
SELECT SUM (under_18 + a18_to_19 + age_20), neighborhood_code 
FROM public.uscb_acs_14to18_age
GROUP BY neighborhood_code
```

Whats next?

Comment: looks ok -- are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: No, but I want to finish of the question... To get each borough and neighborhood

Comment: i think you'll need to give us more information about the table structure.  sounds like you can add `, borough` before `FROM` and after `GROUP BY`, but not sure until we see the table structure

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM (under_18 + a18_to_19 + age_20)
  , neighborhood_code 
FROM public.uscb_acs_14to18_age
GROUP BY neighborhood_code
ORDER BY 1 DESC -- first column in the results
LIMIT 1; -- Just one result is what you need
```